Differences between columns containing lists
I have a data frame where the columns values are list and want to find the differences between two columns.
data={'NAME':['JOHN','MARY','CHARLIE'],
      'A':[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]],
      'B':[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

Why doesn't it work?
df = df.assign(X1 = lambda x: [y for y in x['A'] if y not in x['B']])

I get error :

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I don't understand why?

For clarity, could you describe the logic and add the expected output?

So, this is where lambdas get interesting. These two lambdas will have the same result:
df = df.assign(X1 = lambda x: [y for y in x['A']]) #unvectorized, x is the entire DataFrame
df = df.assign(X1 = lambda x: x['A']) #vectorized, x is a single row

One (lengthy) way to do what you are asking is to iterate through each row, and then compare the nested lists:
df = df.assign(X1 = lambda x: [[y for y in x['A'][i] if y not in x['B'][i]] for i in range(len(x['A']))])

which can be simplified to one of the following
df = df.assign(X1 = [[y for y in r.A if y not in r.B] for i, r in df.iterrows()]) #similar structure to your initial solution
df = df.assign(X2 = [list(set(r.A).difference(r.B)) for i, r in df.iterrows()]) #more efficient, especially for larger sets

Edit:
Pulling in elements of @user19077881's answer, the row-wise operations do work if you use df.apply instead of df.assign
df['X1'] = df.apply(lambda r: [y for y in r.A if y not in r.B], axis=1)
df['X1'] = df.apply(lambda r: list(set(r.A).difference(r.B)), axis=1)


I am assuming you want the difference between the Lists in 'A' and 'B' columns for each row. In which case you could use (for elements in A not in B):
def func(row):
    return list(set(row['A']) - set(row['B']))

df['X1'] = df.apply(func, axis = 1)

which gives:
      NAME          A          B   X1
0     JOHN  [1, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 4]  [1]
1     MARY  [2, 3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]  [2]
2  CHARLIE  [3, 4, 5]  [4, 5, 6]  [3]

Alternatively if you want all elements not in BOTH A and B then use the symmetric difference between the Sets:
def func(row):
    return list(set(row['A']) ^ set(row['B']))

which gives:
      NAME          A          B      X1
0     JOHN  [1, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 4]  [1, 4]
1     MARY  [2, 3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]  [2, 5]
2  CHARLIE  [3, 4, 5]  [4, 5, 6]  [3, 6]


Global comparison
If you want to compare each list to all the lists in B.
There are two issues, you can't use lst in Series as lists are not hashable, and you should use a ternary with None:
df.assign(X1 = lambda x: [y if y not in x['B'].tolist() else None
                          for y in x['A']])

A potentially more efficient approach using a set of tuples (tuples are hashable):
A = df['A'].apply(tuple)
B = set(df['B'].apply(tuple))
df['X1'] = [None if a in B else list(a)
            for a in A]

Output:
      NAME          A          B         X1
0     JOHN  [1, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 4]  [1, 2, 3]
1     MARY  [2, 3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]       None
2  CHARLIE  [3, 4, 5]  [4, 5, 6]       None

Row-wise comparison
If you want to perform a row-wise comparison, the loop over the pairs, using a set for efficiency:
df['X1'] = [[x for x in a if x not in b] for a, b
            in zip(df['A'], df['B'].apply(set))]

Output:
      NAME          A          B   X1
0     JOHN  [1, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 4]  [1]
1     MARY  [2, 3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]  [2]
2  CHARLIE  [3, 4, 5]  [4, 5, 6]  [3]


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'NAME': ['JOHN', 'MARY', 'CHARLIE'],
'A': [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]],
'B': [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Find the difference between the lists in columns 'A' and 'B'
#Vectorized difference using numpy
df['X1'] = [np.setdiff1d(a, b).tolist() for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]

print(df)
'''
      NAME          A          B   X1
0     JOHN  [1, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 4]  [1]
1     MARY  [2, 3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]  [2]
2  CHARLIE  [3, 4, 5]  [4, 5, 6]  [3]
'''

